# How do you paste rows one under the other based on the number given in another sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So, here's the thing. I have an excel workbook with two worksheets. 
Worksheet 1: People tell me how many items they own per category. 
Worksheet 2: People give me details for each item.

And I would like Worksheet 2 to already contain the rows, so they only have to add the details. So I basically want to prepopulate it.

Here is table 1 / Worksheet 1: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dx6EJ.jpg)
So I give people the ID and the category and they add the quantity

[image]

And here is table 2 / Worksheet 2: 
That's what it should look like (I manually pasted the ID and the Category but the table should be prepopulated **automatically**)
[image]

I know you could do that with a Macro. But my organization doesn't really like Macros so I am looking for a formula.

I really appreciate your help on this!

Thanks, 
B

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not require VBA.

**In sheet 1:**

- Insert a new column at the beginning so that all the data is shifted one column to the right (A becomes B, B becomes C etc).
- In cell `A2`,enter 1. Then in `A3` enter `=A2+D2`, then fill this formula down to `A6`
- From `F1` to `F6`, enter the numbers 1 to 6 consecutively (1 in F1, 2 in F2 etc)
- Hide column A and F

**Now move to sheet 2**

- In cell `A2`, enter the formula `=VLOOKUP(ROW(A2),Sheet1!$A$2:$C$5,2)` and fill it down to `A6`
- In cell `B2`, enter the formula `=VLOOKUP(ROW(B2),Sheet1!$A$2:$C$5,3)` and fill it down to B6

The formulas in sheet 2 can now be extended/filled down further as required to capture all the data in sheet 1.

The final result (sheet 2) looks like this:

[image: Result]